# How to select a string between 2 identical characters in SQL

Tags: sql-server, substring, charindex

My initial string is

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="0001.zam"
```

I want to select everything between the two " characters ("0001.zam" in this case). I know that I need to use the SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX functions similar to:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Attachment, CHARINDEX('"', @Attachment),...)
```

I can't figure out what to pass as the second SUBSTRING argument. Note that the string between the two " characters and the string after the second " character are variable. The entire string can look eg. like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="0001556.txt"; size=187;
```

The bottom line is to get everything between the two " characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to get the data you want it to use `left()` and `right()` functions.

```
select left(right(t, len(t)- CHARINDEX('"', t)), charindex('"',right(t, len(t)- CHARINDEX('"', t)))-1)
from
(
select 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="0001.zam"' t
) u
```

This outputs

`0001.zam`

I am hoping, rather than assuming, that there are only two " in this header.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, there will only be two " characters in the whole string.

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `SUBSTRING`, which you tried at the beginning:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Attachment,
                 CHARINDEX('"', @Attachment)+1,
                 CHARINDEX('"', @Attachment,CHARINDEX('"', @Attachment)+1)-CHARINDEX('"', @Attachment)-1)
```